# No Data Found for Heart Rate in Data Recorder - Galaxy Watch

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am having difficulty retrieving heart rate data from the HumanActivityMonitorManager. Specifically, I am using a query with the readRecorderData function but not returning the proper results.

When I check the console, I see the error: "NotFoundError: Failed to read recorded data". According to the docs this means there is no data found.

Samsung Galaxy Watch. 46mm. Tizen Studio.

```
var query = {};
query.startTime =(new Date(2019, 6, 5)).getTime() / 1000;
query.endTime = (new Date(2019, 7, 31)).getTime() / 1000;
query.anchorTime = (new Date(2019, 7, 31, 0, 0)).getTime() / 1000;
query.interval = 1440; /* Day */

var type = "HRM";

try{
    tizen.humanactivitymonitor.readRecorderData(type, query, onread, onerror);
}
catch (err){
    console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
}
```

This should retrieve the HRM data. This works if I change the type to Pedometer or Pressure. I can get the data in real time but would love to be able to get the data already being grabbed by the device.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

HRM data require a few seconds to get its initial value. Have you allowed enough time for the system to record the HRM by calling `tizen.humanactivitymonitor.start('HRM', onchangedCB);` and wait for `onchangedCB`? You need to do `readRecorderData` when humanactivitymonitor says it's ready to give you the data as in the reference.

Refer to https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/sensors/human-activity-monitor?langredirect=1 for more detail.